# RegExp - Match the shortest amount possible does not seem to work

Tags: regex, linux

I want to remove commas within matching double quotes within a CSV file. The key here is that it has to be between matching double quotes. This RexExp does not seem to work:

```
".*?,.*?"
```

It does not find anything if the question mark is introduced. So the following does not work:

```
s/\(".*?\),\(.*?"\)/\1;\2/g
```

The following line is the input test line. It is not matching the shortest one.

```
21,C,101,1,,W,D,,"AAAAAAAA,, RBBBBBB,",CCCCCCCCCC DD EEEEEEEEEE,FFFFFF GGGGGGG HHHHHHHHH,III 101 JJ,,,,KKKKKKK LLLLLLLL M'MMMM N,"OOO, P'PPPP QQQQQQQQ RR R",SSSSSSSSSSSS TTTTTTTTTT,UUU 101 VV,,,,,12/1/1998,1/1/2050,ZZZZZZ
```

I want to change the comma in **"AAAAAAAA,, RBBBBBB,"** to a semicolon **"AAAAAAAA;; RBBBBBB;"**, and **"OOO, P'PPPP QQQQQQQQ RR R"** to **"OOO; P'PPPP QQQQQQQQ RR R"** without changing any other comma in the input line.

Comment: Your regex will fail for CSVs like `"a b", "c d"`.  Regex is not really the tool for CSVs, but if you describe your problem on a higher level we could help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your regex has a fundamental problem: the `.` can match any character, including a quote. The lazy quantifier does not fix that, it merely make it work in simple cases.

Also, what do you want to do if there are multiple commas

Try this instead:

```
"[^",]*?,[^",]*"
```

Or, to handle multiple commas inside the quote:

```
"([^",]*?,)+[^",]*"
```

Note that this regex can still match unwanted text, if you want to avoid that alltogether you have to make it much more complicated to match the line start anchor and real pairs of quotes and not just any two quotes with a comma within.

Comment: Thanks Lucero. Your solution works as long as there is no comma in the square brakets and the question mark is not used. Some how adding the question mark the pattern is not found. **"[^"]*,[^"]*"**. I wander why the question mark is not working. I am going to keep testing.

Comment: Correcting what I wrote, your solution partially works (leaving the comma in both square brackets) if there is only one comma within the quotes to replace using `s/....../g`. You are right on that. Also the RegExp with the question mark in somehow does not find anything. In addition, if there is more than one comma I cannot use your second RegExp with `\1` or `\2` within the `s/...../g` to replace.

Comment: @Guasqueño, there are different regex flavors and capacities around, so your mielage may vary depending on the actual tool used. That being said, I tested it successfully with the JavaScript regex and the .NET regex engines. If the question mark does not work, you can remove it, it will not break the regex in my case, but it may indicate that the regex engine you're using does not support lazy quantifiers. Regarding the caputed groups, you can use `"(?:[^",]*,)+[^",]*"` to avoid a capture being taken.

Comment: I am using Redhat Linux 2.6.32 and TextPad 4.5.0. None of them likes the Lazy question mark. I'll investigate more about the question mark used to avoid capture. That is new to me. Thanks.

Comment: To be more specific, I am trying to use the RegEx inside `vi` in Linux.

Comment: I was able to find a way but it requires to several iterations, I mean to run three different commands, one of them several times. It involves adding a comma at the beginning of the first capture group and a comma at the end of the second group: **`s/\(,"[^",]*\),\([^"]*",\)/\1;\2/g`**, this assumes that a field I want to change starts with `,"` and ends with `",` I run this several times, and then I run a similar command to deal with fields starting at the beginning of the line and another for those ending at the end of the line.

Comment: @Guasqueño, glad that you were able to find a working solution and thanks for the feedback, other users might appreciate that if they stumble across this question.

Answer (score 0):

gnu-awk with `FPAT` can handle this:

```
awk -v FPAT='"[^"]*"|[^,]*' -v OFS=, '{for(i=1; i<=NF; i++) gsub(/,/, ";", $i)} 1' file.csv
```

`-v FPAT='"[^"]*"|[^,]*'` sets field pattern to `"..."` or anything is not a comma. Once we have individual fields split nicely as double quotes or non-comma ones we just iterate them over and replace comma by semi-colon using `gsub`.

**[Code Demo](http://ideone.com/AKGnBE)**

**Output:**

```
21,C,101,1,,W,D,,"AAAAAAAA RBBBBBB;",CCCCCCCCCC DD EEEEEEEEEE,FFFFFF GGGGGGG HHHHHHHHH,III 101 JJ,,,,KKKKKKK LLLLLLLL M'MMMM N,"OOO; P'PPPP QQQQQQQQ RR R",SSSSSSSSSSSS TTTTTTTTTT,UUU 101 VV,,,,,12/1/1998,1/1/2050,ZZZZZZ
```

Comment: Sorry. I run your command and got semicolons where they should not be. I got this: `21;C;101;1;;W;D;;";AAAAAAAA;;,RBBBBBB;";CCCCCCCCCC,DD,EEEEEEEEEE;FFFFFF,GGGGGGG,HHHHHHHHH;III,101,JJ;;;;KKKKKKK,LLLLLLLL,M'MMMM,N;"OOO;,P'PPPP,QQQQQQQQ,RR,R";SSSSSSSSSSSS,TTTTTTTTTT;UUU,101,VV;;;;;12/1/1998;1/1/2050;ZZZZZZ`

Comment: What is the exact command you ran and what is your awk version? I have included awk's output in my answer as well.

Answer (score 0):

I've tested this to work on your sample input:

```
s/\("[^"]*\),\([^"]*"\)/\1;\2/g
```

Execution on OSX and linux with same result:

```
$ echo 21,C,101,1,,W,D,,\"AAAAAAAA,, RBBBBBB,\",CCCCCCCCCC DD EEEEEEEEEE,FFFFFF GGGGGGG HHHHHHHHH,III 101 JJ,,,,KKKKKKK LLLLLLLL M\'MMMM N,\"OOO, P\'PPPP QQQQQQQQ RR R\",SSSSSSSSSSSS TTTTTTTTTT,UUU 101 VV,,,,,12/1/1998,1/1/2050,ZZZZZZ | sed -e 's/\("[^"]*\),\([^"]*"\)/\1;\2/g'
21,C,101,1,,W,D,,"AAAAAAAA,, RBBBBBB;",CCCCCCCCCC DD EEEEEEEEEE,FFFFFF GGGGGGG HHHHHHHHH,III 101 JJ,,,,KKKKKKK LLLLLLLL M'MMMM N,"OOO; P'PPPP QQQQQQQQ RR R",SSSSSSSSSSSS TTTTTTTTTT,UUU 101 VV,,,,,12/1/1998,1/1/2050,ZZZZZZ
```

Comment: `?` after a quantifier means "as few as possible" (lazy matching).

Comment: If the question mark means "as few as possible" how come it does not find at least the one that is found without the question mark?

Comment: Your proposal would change commas within non-matching quotes. For instance in `"aaaa bbbb",xxxx,"bbb"`

Comment: @Guasqueño I have updated my answer to include command results. Your sample input has commas in between matching double quotes which are not affected by the regex. I doesn't deal with multiple commas within matching double quotes, anyway.